# Adding paging to and ASP ListView working with VB

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, oracle, paging

I'm trying to set up paging for a site I'm working on, I'm using a list view. I've done a lot of reading but nothing seems to make sense to me. below is the type of code query I am doing, I'm working in VB and oracle:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="listItemWrap">
        <div class="leadListItem">
            <div class="left leadListCol1 borderNone">
                <h3 class="upperCase"><%#Eval("lead_name")%></h3>
                <h3><%# Eval("leadcode")%></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="left leadListCol2">
                <h3>EMAILS <span>
                    <asp:Image ID="EmailsTickCross" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/Layout/Tick.jpg" /></span></h3>
                <h3>CALLS <span>
                    <asp:Image ID="CallsTickCross" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/Layout/Cross.jpg" /></span></h3>
                <h3>POSTAL <span>
                    <asp:Image ID="PostalTickCross" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/Layout/Tick.jpg" /></span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="left leadListCol3">
                <h3>LATEST INSIGHT VISIT:</h3>
                <p class="upperCase"><%# CType(Eval("last_insight"), Date).ToString("dd-MMM-yy")%></p>
            </div>
            <div class="left leadListCol4">
                <asp:Button ID="ActiveProfileBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("leadcode")%>' runat="server" Text="VIEW PROFILE" CssClass="viewProfile right" />
                <h3>LATEST HPB ACTIVITY:</h3>
                <p>NA</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <div class="leadListNotes">
                <h3>NOTES:</h3>
                <p><%# GetNotes(Eval("leadcode"))%></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

VB:

```
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        Dim oCnn As New OracleConnection(OracleConnectionString)
        Dim da As New OracleDataAdapter("select * from web_table", oCnn)
        Try
            oCnn.Open()
            da.Fill(DT)
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            oCnn.Close()
        End Try

        ActiveLeadsListView.DataSource = DT
        ActiveLeadsListView.DataBind()
```

Any help with this would be great, I'm really stuck with this one. There are around 20000 rows so I definitely need paging.

Comment: You can use [ROW_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm#SQLRF06100) to assign a number to each row. And then filter on that column to only get rows 20 to 30 for example.

Comment: So would you then just increase or decrease a parameter each time a button is clicked then run the query again with the new rows? something like that?

Comment: Yes, something like that.